# Acsess from function to non-global variables

Tags: python

I found a very strange thing in Python. When trying to access an ordinary object (like `int`, `float`, etc.) from some function it's asking me to define the variable to be a global variable.

But when I tried to do the same with `Queue` the result was different; in that situation I could approach the `Queue` from the function even when I didn't make it global.

How can some objects act like globals (`Queue`, for example) and some others not (like `int`, `string`, etc.)?

I clear myself:
Here is two code samples:
some def:

```
def some_def():
    q.put(1)
```

some main:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
```

On the other object:
some def:

```
def some_def():
    number += 1
```

some main:

```
number = 0
```

The two different code samples will act each one different way:
The first one will put the value in the Queue, while the second will throw an Error because 'number' is not a global variable.

Comment: please show minimal code samples with full stack traces

Comment: As mentioned, please post the code in question

Comment: You're confusing two different things: mutable and immutable objects. If you reassigned a name that pointed to something mutable (like a queue, list, dictionary, ...) you'd get the same behaviour as reassigning an integer or string. It's only when you *mutate* the mutable (e.g. `list.append`) that you can change the state of a "global" object.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4630543/3001761, http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, ...

Comment: @Craig Burgler edited

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont think its my issue. see the editing i did and tell me if its the issue you talk about

Comment: @dfsfgsfg it's exactly the same. You are *mutating* `q` using its `put` method, **not** assigning a new value to the name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if i understood right - in python, if i bind between a name and a mutable object, then i can use that name in function that i didnt bind this name in there scope. why python act like this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i mean - why does python act in another way to objects that have method call? in the link you sent me the guy saied: "because nothing local shadows them." but it doesnt saied anything to me...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you still don't understand. There's no *"act in another way"* and there's plenty of material out there on Python's naming and binding model. I can onto suggest that you read more of it.